# Laravel Auth::attempt wont work

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I saw a lot of question relevant to my problem. But none of any solution work in my case.

**My Problem:**
When I am trying `Auth::attempt()` to login it shows this message.

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given, called in D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php on line 371 and defined' in D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php:104
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php(104): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', 'D:\Workshop\Xam...', 104, Array)
#1 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php(371): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->validateCredentials(Object(User), Array)
#2 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php(352): Illuminate\Auth\Guard->hasValidCredentials(Object(User), Array)
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array)
#4 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(8177): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(3227): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('attempt', Array)
#6 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(3227): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->attempt(Array)
#7 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\app\controllers\AccountController.php(31): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('attempt', Array)
#8 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\app\controllers\AccountController.php(31): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::attempt(Array)
#9 [internal function]: AccountController->postLogin()
#10 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(5784): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postLogin', Array)
#12 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(5772): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(AccountController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postLogin')
#13 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(4971): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'AccountControll...', 'postLogin')
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#15 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(5330): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#16 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(4996): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(4984): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(717): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(7706): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(8309): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#22 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(8256): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#23 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(10895): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#24 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\bootstrap\compiled.php(659): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 D:\Workshop\Xampp\htdocs\TP_MAIN\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#26 {main}
```

**Log in Form:**

```
{{-- Form start --}}
<form action="{{ URL::route('log_in') }}" method="post">
<input name="loginemail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
<input name="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" type="password">
{ Form::token() }}

<input type="submit" value="Sign In" />

</form> 
{{-- form end --}}
```

**User model:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $fillable = array('fullname', 'password', 'email', 'code', 'active', 'account_type', 'team_id', 'image_path', 'token');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function postLogin(){

        $loginvalidation = Validator::make(
            [
                'loginemail' => Input::get('loginemail'),
                'loginpassword' => Input::get('loginpassword'),
            ],
            [
                'loginemail' => 'required|email',
                'loginpassword' => 'required'
            ]
        );

         if($loginvalidation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }
        else{
            $loginemail = Input::get('loginemail');
            $loginpassword = Input::get('loginpassword');

            try {

                $auth = Auth::attempt(array(         
                        'email' => $loginemail,
                        'password' => $loginpassword,
                        'active' => 1
                    ));

                if($auth){
                    return Redirect::route('home');
                }

            } catch(Exception $e){
                echo "<pre>".$e."</pre>";
            }
        }

    }
```

**I have already checked this issues:**

1. My password is hashed upon creating it to the database.
2. My password field in my database is varchar 255.
3. The user I'm trying to log in is already created.

Can anybody give me a hint regarding this error? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mystic laravel and his mysterious error messages. The best way to get to the bottom of this, is to use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and step into the `illuminate` code base.